# Long layover (22h) for elder relative at BKK airport

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, layovers, hotels, bkk

Since I have no experience in longer layover times and my grandmother (philippine citizen) will leave Germany soon to go back to the Philippines, I have a few questions.
They will stay for 22 hours in the Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport. My question is what they generally need to stay there, I've read they need ([source:](https://www.thaiairways.com/sites/en_KR/news/news_announcement/news_detail/news_20210310_01.page) *2. Requirements to Transit/Transfer Passenger to other international destination*):

- RT-PCR laboratory result that COVID-19 is not detected( issued  no more than 72 hours before travelling)
- Fit to Fly health certificate
- A health insurance policy (Including COVID-19 with minimum coverage USD 100,000)

It seems like these requirements are quite excessive, can someone verify that we really need all of this ?

My other questions are how to make my grandmother as comfortable as possible there, I would like to book a hotel. I guess they have to get their luggage because their departure will be 22 hours later, does that mean they have to leave the gate area and go through immigration and security again before departure ? Will there be any issues with that, are there different requirements ? Could they even leave the airport to stay in a hotel ?

Comment: Those requirements seem rather normal to me - what about them seems excessive to you?

Comment: I'm surprised you only mention those 3 points, and not this point  - "_The time period of each Transit/Transfer operation shall not exceed 12 hours_" - as you have said that their stop is 22 hours

Comment: The flight was delayed (we bought the tickets months ago) by the airline and after 3 calls there is no solution. They need to leave Germany because their visa will expire. It's very hard to find a solution for this situation.

Comment: For the baggage: If it is possible, do not reclaim your baggage. Just take in hand baggage the necessary for one nigh (which you should have in any case: baggages are often lost or delayed and sometimes passengers will be stranded without baggage). But personally, I would check other travels (22h is very stressful). Ev. do the connection here in Europe (IIRC KLM go to Philippines, and for sure other airlines).

Comment: There is an airside hotel which could save going through immigration, baggage claim, security etc etc. https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/bangkok-suvarnabhumi-airport-guide.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best shot to get the latest details and requirements is to put your exact details into IATA at https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

There is an airside hotel in BKK but it's temporarily closed. https://www.miracletransithotel.com/

If the booking is on a single ticket, they should be able to check the baggage all the way through to the final destination. The cutoff for this is typically 24 hours. Call the airline and ask.

As a Philippine citizen your grandmother doesn't need a visa to enter Thailand and if she is fully vaccinated she can just enter Thailand if she is comfortable doing so. She will have to go through immigration and customs. https://www.thaiembassy.com/travel-to-thailand/travel-to-thailand-from-the-philippines

There is a Novotel right in the airport https://www.novotelairportbkk.com/  They also offer day rooms. The best choice here depends on your flying times (and budget).